# How to add line dash in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to make a line dash in Flutter like this?

[image]

Comment: Did you try something? Can you add that thing too?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4858

Comment: try Text('------------------------------------')

Comment: if you want to draw it as a dashed path on the canvas
use this package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/path_drawing

Answer (score 102, accepted):

[As a workaround](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/4858), in your case, you can do something like this

```dart
class MySeparator extends StatelessWidget {
  const MySeparator({Key? key, this.height = 1, this.color = Colors.black})
      : super(key: key);
  final double height;
  final Color color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        const dashWidth = 10.0;
        final dashHeight = height;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / (2 * dashWidth)).floor();
        return Flex(
          children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: dashWidth,
              height: dashHeight,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
              ),
            );
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: Axis.horizontal,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

and use it `const MySeparator()`

```dart
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Material(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 600,
              width: 350,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
              ),
              child: Flex(
                direction: Axis.vertical,
                children: [
                  Expanded(child: Container()),
                  const MySeparator(color: Colors.grey),
                  Container(height: 200),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 58):

```
class DashedLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    double dashWidth = 9, dashSpace = 5, startX = 0;
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..strokeWidth = 1;
    while (startX < size.width) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, 0), Offset(startX + dashWidth, 0), paint);
      startX += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

Comment: Use it like  CustomPaint(painter: DashedLinePainter());

Comment: This answer deserves more votes and should be accepted answer.

Comment: This answer is the right solution.

Answer (score 33):

```dart
// garis putus putus
Row(
children: List.generate(150~/10, (index) => Expanded(
 child: Container(
  color: index%2==0?Colors.transparent
  :Colors.grey,
  height: 2,
 ),
 )),
),
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: this is the simplest answer to implement without any dependency.

Comment: Looks good trick but why 150~/10  ? why not you used just a number like 15, 16, 17.... ?

Comment: @Deven for example, you want to apply the width of the widget or screen, then divide by how many lines you want and the "~" sign to give an integer value, and if you want it to be even simpler, you can use your suggestion with fixed numbers like 5, 6,10 and so on

Comment: If you want it to start with a dot (colored dot) instead of transparent. first index 0 is even

 color: index.isEven ? Colors.grey : Colors.transparent

Answer (score 20):

The following code creates a dashed path not only for lines, but for any path you want dashed.

Demo:

[image]

The idea is to take the `originalPath` and move along it, alternately adding dashes and gaps until the entire path has been extracted:

```dart
Path _getDashedPath(
  Path originalPath,
  double dashLength,
  double dashGapLength,
) {
  final metricsIterator = originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator;
  while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
    final metric = metricsIterator.current;
    _dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength = 0.0;
    while (_dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength < metric.length) {
      if (_dashedPathProperties.addDashNext) {
        _dashedPathProperties.addDash(metric, dashLength);
      } else {
        _dashedPathProperties.addDashGap(metric, dashGapLength);
      }
    }
  }
  return _dashedPathProperties.path;
}
```

I created a class `DashedPathProperties` to track things like the currently `extractedPathLength` or the `_remainingDashLength`, which becomes relevant if the `originalPath` consists of several sub-paths and a dash (or dash gap) must be continued on the next sub-path:

```dart
class DashedPathProperties {
  double extractedPathLength;
  Path path;

  final double _dashLength;
  double _remainingDashLength;
  double _remainingDashGapLength;
  bool _previousWasDash;

  DashedPathProperties({
    required this.path,
    required double dashLength,
    required double dashGapLength,
  })  : assert(dashLength > 0.0, 'dashLength must be > 0.0'),
        assert(dashGapLength > 0.0, 'dashGapLength must be > 0.0'),
        _dashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashGapLength = dashGapLength,
        _previousWasDash = false,
        extractedPathLength = 0.0;

  //...
}
```

You can use like this (you could wrap your `CustomPaint` in a `ClipRect` if you want to make sure that the painter cannot paint outside of the bounds):

```dart
CustomPaint(
  painter: DashedPathPainter(
    originalPath: Path()
      ..addOval(
        const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100),
      ),
    pathColor: Colors.white,
  ),
  size: const Size(100.0, 100.0),
)
```

Full example code you can run in DartPad:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: ExampleDashedPath(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleDashedPath extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExampleDashedPath({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DashedPathPainter(
            originalPath: Path()..lineTo(100, 0),
            pathColor: Colors.red,
            strokeWidth: 5.0,
            dashGapLength: 10.0,
            dashLength: 10.0,
          ),
          size: const Size(100.0, 2.0),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DashedPathPainter(
            originalPath: Path()
              ..addOval(
                const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100),
              ),
            pathColor: Colors.white,
          ),
          size: const Size(100.0, 100.0),
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 50),
        CustomPaint(
          painter: DashedPathPainter(
            originalPath: Path()
              ..addRect(
                const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100),
              )
              ..lineTo(100, 100),
            pathColor: Colors.grey,
            strokeWidth: 2.0,
            dashLength: 25.0,
          ),
          size: const Size(100.0, 100.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DashedPathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Path originalPath;
  final Color pathColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double dashGapLength;
  final double dashLength;
  late DashedPathProperties _dashedPathProperties;

  DashedPathPainter({
    required this.originalPath,
    required this.pathColor,
    this.strokeWidth = 3.0,
    this.dashGapLength = 5.0,
    this.dashLength = 10.0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _dashedPathProperties = DashedPathProperties(
      path: Path(),
      dashLength: dashLength,
      dashGapLength: dashGapLength,
    );
    final dashedPath = _getDashedPath(originalPath, dashLength, dashGapLength);
    canvas.drawPath(
      dashedPath,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = pathColor
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DashedPathPainter oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.originalPath != originalPath ||
      oldDelegate.pathColor != pathColor ||
      oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth ||
      oldDelegate.dashGapLength != dashGapLength ||
      oldDelegate.dashLength != dashLength;

  Path _getDashedPath(
    Path originalPath,
    double dashLength,
    double dashGapLength,
  ) {
    final metricsIterator = originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator;
    while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
      final metric = metricsIterator.current;
      _dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength = 0.0;
      while (_dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength < metric.length) {
        if (_dashedPathProperties.addDashNext) {
          _dashedPathProperties.addDash(metric, dashLength);
        } else {
          _dashedPathProperties.addDashGap(metric, dashGapLength);
        }
      }
    }
    return _dashedPathProperties.path;
  }
}

class DashedPathProperties {
  double extractedPathLength;
  Path path;

  final double _dashLength;
  double _remainingDashLength;
  double _remainingDashGapLength;
  bool _previousWasDash;

  DashedPathProperties({
    required this.path,
    required double dashLength,
    required double dashGapLength,
  })  : assert(dashLength > 0.0, 'dashLength must be > 0.0'),
        assert(dashGapLength > 0.0, 'dashGapLength must be > 0.0'),
        _dashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashGapLength = dashGapLength,
        _previousWasDash = false,
        extractedPathLength = 0.0;

  bool get addDashNext {
    if (!_previousWasDash || _remainingDashLength != _dashLength) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void addDash(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashLength) {
    // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
    final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashLength);
    final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashLength);
    // Add path
    final pathSegment = metric.extractPath(extractedPathLength, end);
    path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
    // Update
    final delta = _remainingDashLength - (end - extractedPathLength);
    _remainingDashLength = _updateRemainingLength(
      delta: delta,
      end: end,
      availableEnd: availableEnd,
      initialLength: dashLength,
    );
    extractedPathLength = end;
    _previousWasDash = true;
  }

  void addDashGap(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashGapLength) {
    // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
    final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashGapLength);
    final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashGapLength);
    // Move path's end point
    ui.Tangent tangent = metric.getTangentForOffset(end)!;
    path.moveTo(tangent.position.dx, tangent.position.dy);
    // Update
    final delta = end - extractedPathLength;
    _remainingDashGapLength = _updateRemainingLength(
      delta: delta,
      end: end,
      availableEnd: availableEnd,
      initialLength: dashGapLength,
    );
    extractedPathLength = end;
    _previousWasDash = false;
  }

  double _calculateLength(ui.PathMetric metric, double addedLength) {
    return math.min(extractedPathLength + addedLength, metric.length);
  }

  double _updateRemainingLength({
    required double delta,
    required double end,
    required double availableEnd,
    required double initialLength,
  }) {
    return (delta > 0 && availableEnd == end) ? delta : initialLength;
  }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Didn't even have to change my existing code

Comment: I cannot stress enough how ridiculously good the code is. It deserves more attention.

Comment: @hnnngwdlch is there any way to have border radius?

Comment: @DolDurma You just have to pass an `originalPath` that has rounded corners, e.g. `Path()..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(const Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 100, 100), const Radius.circular(10)))`

Answer (score 13):

CustomPainter can help here as well. In this example is a vertical dash line but could be changed easily.

```
class LineDashedPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var paint = Paint()..strokeWidth = 2;
    var max = 35;
    var dashWidth = 5;
    var dashSpace = 5;
    double startY = 0;
    while (max >= 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(0, startY), Offset(0, startY + dashWidth), paint);
      final space = (dashSpace + dashWidth);
      startY += space;
      max -= space;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

and that use CustomPaint Widget:

```
CustomPaint(painter: LineDashedPainter())
```

Answer (score 12):

I have written [flutter_dash](https://github.com/huy-lv/flutter_dash) library for drawing that dash. Just one line and you should have a dash :D

```
Dash(length: 200, dashColor: Colors.red)
```

Give it a try!

Comment: I don't recomend, this library is not well optimized and will cause your app to be slower to load screens

Comment: @SoufianeGhzal please give me some advices to optimize it, thank you

Comment: @LêVũHuy I don't really know what's the issue. go to github please https://github.com/huy-lv/flutter_dash/issues/2

Answer (score 6):

Thank to marksimr answer, here is the code for both vertical and horizontal dash line.

**Horizontal** usage:

```
DashLineView(
  fillRate: 0.7,
),
```

**Vertical** usage:

```
DashLineView(
  fillRate: 0.7,
  direction: Axis.vertical,
),
```

Full code:

```
class DashLineView extends StatelessWidget {
  final double dashHeight;
  final double dashWith;
  final Color dashColor;
  final double fillRate; // [0, 1] totalDashSpace/totalSpace
  final Axis direction;

  DashLineView(
      {this.dashHeight = 1,
      this.dashWith = 8,
      this.dashColor = Colors.black,
      this.fillRate = 0.5,
      this.direction = Axis.horizontal});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxSize = direction == Axis.horizontal
            ? constraints.constrainWidth()
            : constraints.constrainHeight();
        final dCount = (boxSize * fillRate / dashWith).floor();
        return Flex(
          children: List.generate(dCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: direction == Axis.horizontal ? dashWith : dashHeight,
              height: direction == Axis.horizontal ? dashHeight : dashWith,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: dashColor),
              ),
            );
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: direction,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Create this class:

```
class DotWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double totalWidth, dashWidth, emptyWidth, dashHeight;

  final Color dashColor;

  const DotWidget({
    this.totalWidth = 300,
    this.dashWidth = 10,
    this.emptyWidth = 5,
    this.dashHeight = 2,
    this.dashColor = Colors.black,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: List.generate(
        totalWidth ~/ (dashWidth + emptyWidth),
            (_) => Container(
          width: dashWidth,
          height: dashHeight,
          color: dashColor,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: emptyWidth / 2, right: emptyWidth / 2),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

Use it like any other widget

```
 child: DotWidget(
   dashColor: Colors.black,
   dashHeight: 2,
   dashWidth: 100,
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

**Vertical dashed line:** 
I modifed maksimr's example:

```
class DashedLine extends StatelessWidget {
  final double height;
  final double heightContainer;
  final Color color;

  const DashedLine({this.height = 3, this.color = Colors.black, this.heightContainer = 70});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: heightContainer,
      child: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
          final boxHeight = constraints.constrainHeight();
          final dashWidth = 10.0;
          final dashHeight = height;
          final dashCount = (boxHeight / (2 * dashHeight)).floor();
          return Flex(
            children: List.generate(dashCount, (_) {
              return SizedBox(
                width: dashWidth,
                height: dashHeight,
                child: DecoratedBox(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
                ),
              );
            }),
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            direction: Axis.vertical,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CustomPainter** with a **linear gradient dashed shader** for your lines.

```
   // GradientRotation(3.14 / 2) — for vertical lines with dashes
   // GradientRotation(0) — for horizontal lines with dashes
   // .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 10, 10) — 10 is the size of repeated shaders part
   // This method can be tricky if you need a line oriented by some angle.

Paint()..shader = LinearGradient(
                  colors: [Colors.blue, Colors.transparent],
                  stops: [0.5, 0.5],
                  tileMode: TileMode.repeated,
                  transform: GradientRotation(3.14 / 2))
              .createShader(Rect.fromLTWH(0, 0, 10, 10))
          ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
          ..strokeWidth = 6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Row(
    children: List.generate(20, (index) {
                 return Expanded(
                   child: Padding(
                     padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                     child: Container(
                       height: 5,
                       width: 10,
                       color: Color(0XFFf2f2f2),
                     ),
                   ),
                 );
               }),
             )
```

[image]

Comment: this will be not responsive

Answer (score 2):

I created a `CustomPainter` by integrating the solution [here](https://coflutter.com/flutter-how-to-draw-dashed-line-on-canvas/) and the math from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/how-to-find-a-point-on-given-line-that-its-distance-from-another-point-is-given). This `CustomPainter` allows to draw a solid line or a dashed line by specifying the length of the dash and the length of the space between dashes. But the best thing is you can even draw the solid or dashed line in all directions. I mean horizontal, vertical, and even diagonal!

This is the code for the `CustomPainter`:

```js
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Offset firstOffset;
  final Offset secondOffset;
  final Color color;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double dashLength;
  final double dashSpace;

  const LinePainter({
    required this.firstOffset,
    required this.secondOffset,
    this.color = Colors.black,
    this.strokeWidth = 2.0,
    this.dashLength = 4.0,
    this.dashSpace = 4.0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = color
      ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
    _drawDashedLine(
        dashLength, dashSpace, firstOffset, secondOffset, canvas, size, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }

  void _drawDashedLine(double dashLength, double dashSpace, Offset firstOffset,
      Offset secondOffset, Canvas canvas, Size size, Paint paint) {
    var startOffset = firstOffset;

    var intervals = _getDirectionVector(firstOffset, secondOffset).length /
        (dashLength + dashSpace);

    for (var i = 0; i < intervals; i++) {
      var endOffset = _getNextOffset(startOffset, secondOffset, dashLength);

      /// Draw a small line.
      canvas.drawLine(startOffset, endOffset, paint);

      /// Update the starting offset.
      startOffset = _getNextOffset(endOffset, secondOffset, dashSpace);
    }
  }

  Offset _getNextOffset(
    Offset firstOffset,
    Offset secondOffset,
    double smallVectorLength,
  ) {
    var directionVector = _getDirectionVector(firstOffset, secondOffset);

    var rescaleFactor = smallVectorLength / directionVector.length;
    if (rescaleFactor.isNaN || rescaleFactor.isInfinite) {
      rescaleFactor = 1;
    }

    var rescaledVector = Offset(directionVector.vector.dx * rescaleFactor,
        directionVector.vector.dy * rescaleFactor);

    var newOffset = Offset(
        firstOffset.dx + rescaledVector.dx, firstOffset.dy + rescaledVector.dy);

    return newOffset;
  }

  DirectionVector _getDirectionVector(Offset firstVector, Offset secondVector) {
    var directionVector = Offset(
        secondVector.dx - firstVector.dx, secondVector.dy - firstVector.dy);

    var directionVectorLength =
        sqrt(pow(directionVector.dx, 2) + pow(directionVector.dy, 2));

    return DirectionVector(
      vector: directionVector,
      length: directionVectorLength,
    );
  }
}

class DirectionVector {
  final Offset vector;
  final double length;

  const DirectionVector({
    required this.vector,
    required this.length,
  });
}
```

You can use this `CustomPainter` by setting up the `painter` parameter of a `CustomPaint` widget, like this:

```js
CustomPaint(
  painter: LinePainter(
    firstOffset: Offset(0, 0),
    secondOffset: Offset(10, 10),
  ),
),
```

The result is shown in the following image:

[image: Dashed line using the CustomPainter]

Answer (score 2):

When going for the `CustomPainter` approach, painting a dashed line in any direction can be achieved by a snippet like this:

```
  void _drawDashedLine(Canvas canvas, Offset start, Offset end, Paint paint) {
    const dashLength = 10.0;
    const stride = 2 * dashLength;

    var distance = (end - start).distance;
    while (distance > 0) {
      final remaining = end - start;
      final direction = remaining / remaining.distance;
      final next = start + (direction * dashLength);
      canvas.drawLine(start, next, paint);
      start = start + (direction * stride);
      distance -= stride;
    }
  }
```

This method should be embedded in your [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) implementation of a [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget, like mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for horizontal dashed line, like your image. **CustomPaint** is highly recommended by flutter team for stuff like this. It is fast and efficient for rendering also. You can play with **Offset** to change the direction.

```
 class MyClass extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: MyLinePainter(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    var max = 100;
    var dashWidth, dashSpace = 5;
    double startX = 0;
    final paint = Paint()..color = Colors.grey;
    while (max >= 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, 0), Offset(startX + dashWidth, 0), paint..strokeWidth = 1);
      final space = (dashSpace + dashWidth);
      startX += space;
      max -= space;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
Widget dashedHorizontalLine(){
  return Row(
    children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        Expanded(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Divider(
                  color: AppColors.darkGreen,
                  thickness: 2,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution.

```
Row(                        // Dashed line
    children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
        Container(
          width: 5,
          height: 1,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              bottom: BorderSide(
                width: 1,
                color: i % 2 == 0
                    ? const Color.fromRGBO(214, 211, 211, 1)
                    : Colors.transparent,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
    ],
  ),
```

Output:

[image: Output:]

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
class DotDivider extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final double gap;
  final Color color;
  final double lineHeight;

  const DotDivider(
      {this.height = 1.0,
      this.color = Colors.black,
      this.width = 2.0,
      this.gap = 2.0,
      this.lineHeight = 10.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxWidth = constraints.constrainWidth();
        final dashWidth = width;
        final dashHeight = height;
        final dashCount = (boxWidth / dashWidth).floor();
        return Container(
          height: (lineHeight * 2) + height,
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: dashCount,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Center(
              child: Container(
                width: dashWidth,
                height: dashHeight,
                margin:
                    EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: lineHeight, horizontal: gap),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer using **CustomPainter** because it's more performance and suitable for such issues.

```
class DashLine extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashLine({
    Key key,
    this.color,
    this.dashWidth,
    this.dashSpace,
    this.strokeWidth,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final double dashWidth;
  final double dashSpace;
  final double strokeWidth;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _DashLinePainter(
        color: color,
        dashWidth: dashWidth,
        dashSpace: dashSpace,
        strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DashLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  _DashLinePainter({
    Color color,
    double dashWidth,
    double dashSpace,
    double strokeWidth,
  })  : _color = color ?? Colors.red,
        _dashWidth = dashWidth ?? 5.0,
        _dashSpace = dashSpace ?? 5.0,
        _strokeWidth = strokeWidth ?? 1.0;

  final Color _color;
  final double _dashWidth;
  final double _dashSpace;
  final double _strokeWidth;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = _color
      ..strokeWidth = _strokeWidth;

    var max = size.width;
    var startX = 0.0;
    while (max >= 0) {
      canvas.drawLine(Offset(startX, 0), Offset(startX + _dashWidth, 0), paint);
      final space = (_dashSpace + _dashWidth);
      startX += space;
      max -= space;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(_DashLinePainter oldDelegate) {
    return _color != oldDelegate._color ||
        _dashWidth != oldDelegate._dashWidth ||
        _dashSpace != oldDelegate._dashSpace ||
        _strokeWidth != oldDelegate._strokeWidth;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dotted_line: ^3.0.0` lib which provides dashed lines and many more [link](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_line)

```
import 'package:dotted_line/dotted_line.dart';

DottedLine(
  direction: Axis.horizontal,
  lineLength: double.infinity,
  lineThickness: 1.0,
  dashLength: 4.0,
  dashColor: Colors.grey,
  dashRadius: 0.0,
  dashGapLength: 4.0,
  dashGapColor: Colors.transparent,
  dashGapRadius: 0.0,
)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
class dotWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const dotWidget({super.key,});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: List.generate(45, (index) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 6.0),
          child: Container(height: 1, width: 1, color: Colors.grey.shade500),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

then call the widgets

Answer (score -1):

```
Container(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  height: 40.0,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "---------------------------------------------------------------------------",
                      maxLines: 1,
                      style: typoNormalTextRegular.copyWith(
                          color: colorABGray),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
```

> Only use Text Widget, easy solution

Comment: are you serious?

Comment: wild and creative idea! Nice!

Answer (score -1):

To have horizontal dashed line I have made following custom class:

**Custom Painter Class:**

```
class DrawDottedhorizontalline extends CustomPainter {
  Paint _paint;
  DrawDottedhorizontalline() {
    _paint = Paint();
    _paint.color = Colors.black; //dots color
    _paint.strokeWidth = 2; //dots thickness
    _paint.strokeCap = StrokeCap.square; //dots corner edges
  }

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    for (double i = -300; i < 300; i = i + 15) {
      // 15 is space between dots
      if (i % 3 == 0)
        canvas.drawLine(Offset(i, 0.0), Offset(i + 10, 0.0), _paint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Use:**

```
 Container(
               color: Colors.white,
                height: 150.0, //height of container
                child: Center(
                  child:CustomPaint(painter: DrawDottedhorizontalline()),
                  //drawing horizontal dotted/dash line          
                ),
            ),
```