# Creating Dot Leaders for Menu in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a menu in Flutter with dot leaders and I'm having trouble with this.

The format I'm looking for is the picture posted below.

[Link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O55FG.png)

Can someone please help me with this ?

Comment: Follow this you may get your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019785/how-to-add-line-dash-in-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom painter like this to draw a dotted line:

```
import 'dart:math';

class DottedLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  
  // A pattern [4, 2] means a line of width 4 px followed by a gap of 2 px.
  final List<double> pattern;
  
  // For shifting the line up (negative) or down (positive)
  final double verticalOffset;

  final Color strokeColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
 
  // Padding at start and end
  final double indent;

  DottedLinePainter({
    @required this.pattern,
    this.verticalOffset = 0,
    this.indent = 0,
    this.strokeColor: Colors.black,
    this.strokeWidth: 1,
  });

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter old) => true;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    int p = 0;

    final double w = size.width - 2 * indent;
    double start = indent;

    while (start < w) {
      if (p.isEven) {
        canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(min(start, w), verticalOffset),
          Offset(min(start + pattern[p], w), verticalOffset),
          Paint()
            ..color = strokeColor
            ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
          // You can access more properties here if you need more customization
        );
      }
      start += pattern[p];
      p = (p + 1) % pattern.length;
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you can do something like this:

```
Row(
  children: [
    Text("QUAIL"),
    Expanded(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: DottedLinePainter(
          pattern: [4, 2], // A line segment of length 4 px and then a blank of length 2 px
          indent: 4, // 4 px of padding at the start and the end
          verticalOffset: 3.5, // Shift the line 3.5 px down from the center
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Text("9.9"),
  ],
);
```

Result:

[image: Result]