# Flutter - Add a dashed line as progress indicator for a multi-page Registration flow

Tags: flutter, user-interface, progress-bar, user-experience

The project has 4 registration screens with a dynamic header that displays the current page by the means of color. Below is the state when we move to the first page

[image: Reuqired - Step 1]

Once we complete pages and move on, the indicator for the completed steps changes color and state should be as below

[image: Required - Step 3]

I am able to achieve the icon set and color difference, but I am not able to implement the dashed line between the items. Here are the WIP widgets. Please ignore the icon mismatch

[image]

[image]

Here's the code for Generating the header

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 18.0, top: 12),
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(14),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        RegisterStepWidget(
            title: "Basic Details",
            icon: Drawables.icBasicDetails,
            currentStep: currentStep,
            stepIndex: 1),
        RegisterStepWidget(
            title: "Contact Details",
            icon: Drawables.icContactDetails,
            currentStep: currentStep,
            stepIndex: 2),
        RegisterStepWidget(
            title: "Extra Details",
            icon: Drawables.icExtraDetails,
            currentStep: currentStep,
            stepIndex: 3),
        RegisterStepWidget(
            title: "Garda Vetting",
            icon: Drawables.icBasicDetails,
            currentStep: currentStep,
            stepIndex: 4),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

Individual Widget

```
class RegisterStepWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RegisterStepWidget(
      {Key? key,
      required this.title,
      required this.icon,
      required this.currentStep,
      required this.stepIndex})
      : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  final String icon;
  final int currentStep;
  final int stepIndex;

  bool get isCompleted => currentStep > stepIndex;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          icon,
          width: 28,
          color: isCompleted ? ColorResource.blueGray : ColorResource.darkBlue,
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        Text(
          title,
          style: GoogleFonts.notoSans(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: isCompleted
                  ? ColorResource.blueGray
                  : ColorResource.darkBlue),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change MainAxisAlignment to start and use in middle of widgets

```
DashLineView(
  fillRate: 0.7,
),
```

.

```
class DashLineView extends StatelessWidget {
  final double dashHeight;
  final double dashWith;
  final Color dashColor;
  final double fillRate; // [0, 1] totalDashSpace/totalSpace
  final Axis direction;

  DashLineView(
      {this.dashHeight = 1,
      this.dashWith = 8,
      this.dashColor = Colors.black,
      this.fillRate = 0.5,
      this.direction = Axis.horizontal});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
        final boxSize = direction == Axis.horizontal
            ? constraints.constrainWidth()
            : constraints.constrainHeight();
        final dCount = (boxSize * fillRate / dashWith).floor();
        return Flex(
          children: List.generate(dCount, (_) {
            return SizedBox(
              width: direction == Axis.horizontal ? dashWith : dashHeight,
              height: direction == Axis.horizontal ? dashHeight : dashWith,
              child: DecoratedBox(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: dashColor),
              ),
            );
          }),
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          direction: direction,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Modify accordingly

original credit -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69566783/15519056)