# How to build RoadMap UI using a dotted line

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation, flutter-ui

I'm trying to recreate this roadmap-style UI:

[image: Example]

I thought tentatively:

```
children: [

index 1: ListTile
index 2: dotted
index 3: ListTile
index 4: dotted
...
```

But in the picture, the intersecting line looks as if it goes under the circle and comes out.

I would be grateful if I could be helped to achieve the same result. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you try some code. Without some effort it will be hard to provide the overall written code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a road map widget based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71099304/8204173) solution for the dash line.

The road map widget consists of two main parts: the dashed line section and the section for drawing icons on the dashed line.

**Dashed curve line**

```
Path _customPath(Size size, double painterCornerRad, double iconSize, int iconCount) {
    final width = size.width;
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(iconSize / 2, iconSize / 2);

    for (int i = 1; i < iconCount; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        path
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(-painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: true,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          )
          ..relativeLineTo(-width + (painterCornerRad * 2) + iconSize, 0)
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(-painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: false,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          );
      } else {
        path
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: false,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          )
          ..relativeLineTo(width - (painterCornerRad * 2) - iconSize, 0)
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: true,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          );
      }
    }

    return path;
  }
```

**Icon on the dotted line**

I use a `Stack` to display the icon with calculated width and height to ensure that it fits the dash line path perfectly.

```
CustomPaint(
      painter: DashedPathPainter(
        originalPath: (size) {
          return _customPath(size, pathCornerRad, iconSize, icons.length);
        },
        pathColor: Colors.black87,
        strokeWidth: 1.5,
        dashGapLength: 5.0,
        dashLength: 10.0,
      ),
      child: SizedBox(
          width: layoutSize,
          height: (pathCornerRad * 2) * (icons.length - 1) + iconSize,
          child: Stack(
              children: icons
          )
      ),
    )
```

Icon list wrapped by `Positioned`

```
final icons = List.generate(20, (index) {
      final left = index == 0 || index % 2 == 0;
      return Positioned(
        left: left ? 0 : null,
        right: left ? null : 0,
        top: index * (pathCornerRad * 2),
        child: Container(
          width: iconSize,
          height: iconSize,
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.blue,
            shape: BoxShape.circle
          ),
          child: const Icon(Icons.question_mark_rounded, color: Colors.white)
        ),
      );
    });
```

You can set the value to your preference or make it the parameter of the widget.

```
const iconSize = 40.0; // Size of the icon
const pathCornerRad = 44.0; // Corner radius of the curved line
const layoutSize = 350.0; // TThe width of the path can stretch to.
```

Below is the complete source code that you can easily copy and paste to run on [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/).

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: ExampleRoadMap(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ExampleRoadMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleRoadMap({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleRoadMap> createState() => _ExampleRoadMapState();
}

class _ExampleRoadMapState extends State<ExampleRoadMap> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const iconSize = 40.0;
    const pathCornerRad = 44.0;
    const layoutSize = 350.0;
    final icons = List.generate(20, (index) {
      final left = index == 0 || index % 2 == 0;
      return Positioned(
        left: left ? 0 : null,
        right: left ? null : 0,
        top: index * (pathCornerRad * 2),
        child: Container(
            width: iconSize,
            height: iconSize,
            decoration:
                const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
            child:
                const Icon(Icons.question_mark_rounded, color: Colors.white)),
      );
    });
    return Center(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomPaint(
              painter: DashedPathPainter(
                originalPath: (size) {
                  return _customPath(
                      size, pathCornerRad, iconSize, icons.length);
                },
                pathColor: Colors.black87,
                strokeWidth: 1.5,
                dashGapLength: 5.0,
                dashLength: 10.0,
              ),
              child: SizedBox(
                  width: layoutSize,
                  height: (pathCornerRad * 2) * (icons.length - 1) + iconSize,
                  child: Stack(children: icons)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Path _customPath(Size size, double painterCornerRad, double iconSize,
      int destinationIcon) {
    final width = size.width;
    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(iconSize / 2, iconSize / 2);

    for (int i = 1; i < destinationIcon; i++) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        path
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(-painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: true,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          )
          ..relativeLineTo(-width + (painterCornerRad * 2) + iconSize, 0)
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(-painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: false,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          );
      } else {
        path
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: false,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          )
          ..relativeLineTo(width - (painterCornerRad * 2) - iconSize, 0)
          ..relativeArcToPoint(
            Offset(painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
            clockwise: true,
            radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
          );
      }
    }

    return path;
  }
}

class DashedPathPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final Path Function(Size) originalPath;
  final Color pathColor;
  final double strokeWidth;
  final double dashGapLength;
  final double dashLength;
  late DashedPathProperties _dashedPathProperties;

  DashedPathPainter({
    required this.originalPath,
    required this.pathColor,
    this.strokeWidth = 3.0,
    this.dashGapLength = 5.0,
    this.dashLength = 10.0,
  });

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    _dashedPathProperties = DashedPathProperties(
      path: Path(),
      dashLength: dashLength,
      dashGapLength: dashGapLength,
    );
    final dashedPath =
        _getDashedPath(originalPath.call(size), dashLength, dashGapLength);
    canvas.drawPath(
      dashedPath,
      Paint()
        ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
        ..color = pathColor
        ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DashedPathPainter oldDelegate) =>
      oldDelegate.originalPath != originalPath ||
      oldDelegate.pathColor != pathColor ||
      oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth ||
      oldDelegate.dashGapLength != dashGapLength ||
      oldDelegate.dashLength != dashLength;

  Path _getDashedPath(
    Path originalPath,
    double dashLength,
    double dashGapLength,
  ) {
    final metricsIterator = originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator;
    while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
      final metric = metricsIterator.current;
      _dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength = 0.0;
      while (_dashedPathProperties.extractedPathLength < metric.length) {
        if (_dashedPathProperties.addDashNext) {
          _dashedPathProperties.addDash(metric, dashLength);
        } else {
          _dashedPathProperties.addDashGap(metric, dashGapLength);
        }
      }
    }
    return _dashedPathProperties.path;
  }
}

class DashedPathProperties {
  double extractedPathLength;
  Path path;

  final double _dashLength;
  double _remainingDashLength;
  double _remainingDashGapLength;
  bool _previousWasDash;

  DashedPathProperties({
    required this.path,
    required double dashLength,
    required double dashGapLength,
  })  : assert(dashLength > 0.0, 'dashLength must be > 0.0'),
        assert(dashGapLength > 0.0, 'dashGapLength must be > 0.0'),
        _dashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashLength = dashLength,
        _remainingDashGapLength = dashGapLength,
        _previousWasDash = false,
        extractedPathLength = 0.0;

  bool get addDashNext {
    if (!_previousWasDash || _remainingDashLength != _dashLength) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  void addDash(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashLength) {
    // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
    final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashLength);
    final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashLength);
    // Add path
    final pathSegment = metric.extractPath(extractedPathLength, end);
    path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
    // Update
    final delta = _remainingDashLength - (end - extractedPathLength);
    _remainingDashLength = _updateRemainingLength(
      delta: delta,
      end: end,
      availableEnd: availableEnd,
      initialLength: dashLength,
    );
    extractedPathLength = end;
    _previousWasDash = true;
  }

  void addDashGap(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashGapLength) {
    // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
    final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashGapLength);
    final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashGapLength);
    // Move path's end point
    ui.Tangent tangent = metric.getTangentForOffset(end)!;
    path.moveTo(tangent.position.dx, tangent.position.dy);
    // Update
    final delta = end - extractedPathLength;
    _remainingDashGapLength = _updateRemainingLength(
      delta: delta,
      end: end,
      availableEnd: availableEnd,
      initialLength: dashGapLength,
    );
    extractedPathLength = end;
    _previousWasDash = false;
  }

  double _calculateLength(ui.PathMetric metric, double addedLength) {
    return math.min(extractedPathLength + addedLength, metric.length);
  }

  double _updateRemainingLength({
    required double delta,
    required double end,
    required double availableEnd,
    required double initialLength,
  }) {
    return (delta > 0 && availableEnd == end) ? delta : initialLength;
  }
}
```

[image]

**Updated Version**

There is a different version where you can set a specific color for each path. If no colors are set for the path index, it will take the `pathColor` as default.

```
    import 'dart:ui' as ui;
    import 'dart:math' as math;
    
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return const MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: ExampleRoadMap(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class ExampleRoadMap extends StatefulWidget {
      const ExampleRoadMap({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<ExampleRoadMap> createState() => _ExampleRoadMapState();
    }
    
    class _ExampleRoadMapState extends State<ExampleRoadMap> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        const iconSize = 60.0;
        const pathCornerRad = 50.0;
        const layoutSize = 350.0;
        final icons = List.generate(15, (index) {
          final left = index == 0 || index % 2 == 0;
          return Positioned(
            left: left ? 0 : null,
            right: left ? null : 0,
            top: index * (pathCornerRad * 2),
            child: Container(
                width: iconSize,
                height: iconSize,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue, shape: BoxShape.circle),
                child: const Icon(Icons.question_mark_rounded, color: Colors.white)),
          );
        });
        return Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                CustomPaint(
                  painter: DashedPathPainter(
                    originalPath: (size) {
                      return _customPath(size, pathCornerRad, iconSize, icons.length);
                    },
                    pathColors: [
                      Colors.orange,
                      Colors.blue,
                      Colors.green,
                      Colors.grey,
                      Colors.indigo,
                      Colors.orangeAccent,
                      Colors.red,
                      Colors.amberAccent,
                      Colors.pink
                    ],
                    pathColor: Colors.black87,
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    dashGapLength: 5.0,
                    dashLength: 10.0,
                  ),
                  child: SizedBox(
                      width: layoutSize,
                      height: (pathCornerRad * 2) * (icons.length - 1) + iconSize,
                      child: Stack(children: icons)),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      List<Path> _customPath(Size size, double painterCornerRad, double iconSize, int iconCount) {
        final width = size.width;
    
        List<Path> paths = [];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < iconCount - 1; i++) {
          final path = Path();
    
          if (i % 2 == 0) {
            final startX = iconSize / 2;
            final startY = (i * painterCornerRad * 2) + (iconSize / 2);
            path.moveTo(startX, startY);
            path
              ..arcToPoint(
                Offset(startX + painterCornerRad, startY + painterCornerRad),
                clockwise: false,
                radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
              )
              ..relativeLineTo(width - (painterCornerRad * 2) - iconSize, 0)
              ..relativeArcToPoint(
                Offset(painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
                clockwise: true,
                radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
              );
          } else {
            final startX = width - iconSize / 2;
            final startY = (i * painterCornerRad * 2) + (iconSize / 2);
            path.moveTo(startX, startY);
            path
              ..arcToPoint(
                Offset(-painterCornerRad + startX, startY + painterCornerRad),
                clockwise: true,
                radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
              )
              ..relativeLineTo(-width + (painterCornerRad * 2) + iconSize, 0)
              ..relativeArcToPoint(
                Offset(-painterCornerRad, painterCornerRad),
                clockwise: false,
                radius: Radius.circular(painterCornerRad),
              );
          }
    
          paths.add(path);
        }
    
        return paths;
      }
    }
    
    class DashedPathPainter extends CustomPainter {
      final List<Path> Function(Size) originalPath;
      final List<Color> pathColors;
      final Color pathColor;
      final double strokeWidth;
      final double dashGapLength;
      final double dashLength;
    
      DashedPathPainter({
        required this.originalPath,
        required this.pathColors,
        required this.pathColor,
        this.strokeWidth = 3.0,
        this.dashGapLength = 5.0,
        this.dashLength = 10.0,
      });
    
      @override
      void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
        final paths = originalPath.call(size);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
          final dashedPath = _getDashedPath(
              DashedPathProperties(
                path: Path(),
                dashLength: dashLength,
                dashGapLength: dashGapLength,
              ),
              paths[i],
              dashLength,
              dashGapLength);
    
          Color color = pathColor;
          if(i < pathColors.length) {
            color = pathColors[i];
          }
    
          final paint = Paint()
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..color = color
            ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
          canvas.drawPath(dashedPath, paint);
        }
      }
    
      @override
      bool shouldRepaint(DashedPathPainter oldDelegate) =>
          oldDelegate.originalPath != originalPath ||
          oldDelegate.pathColor != pathColor ||
          oldDelegate.pathColors != pathColors ||
          oldDelegate.strokeWidth != strokeWidth ||
          oldDelegate.dashGapLength != dashGapLength ||
          oldDelegate.dashLength != dashLength;
    
      Path _getDashedPath(
        DashedPathProperties pathProps,
        Path originalPath,
        double dashLength,
        double dashGapLength,
      ) {
        final metricsIterator = originalPath.computeMetrics().iterator;
        while (metricsIterator.moveNext()) {
          final metric = metricsIterator.current;
          pathProps.extractedPathLength = 0.0;
          while (pathProps.extractedPathLength < metric.length) {
            if (pathProps.addDashNext) {
              pathProps.addDash(metric, dashLength);
            } else {
              pathProps.addDashGap(metric, dashGapLength);
            }
          }
        }
        return pathProps.path;
      }
    }
    
    class DashedPathProperties {
      double extractedPathLength;
      Path path;
    
      final double _dashLength;
      double _remainingDashLength;
      double _remainingDashGapLength;
      bool _previousWasDash;
    
      DashedPathProperties({
        required this.path,
        required double dashLength,
        required double dashGapLength,
      })  : assert(dashLength > 0.0, 'dashLength must be > 0.0'),
            assert(dashGapLength > 0.0, 'dashGapLength must be > 0.0'),
            _dashLength = dashLength,
            _remainingDashLength = dashLength,
            _remainingDashGapLength = dashGapLength,
            _previousWasDash = false,
            extractedPathLength = 0.0;
    
      bool get addDashNext {
        if (!_previousWasDash || _remainingDashLength != _dashLength) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      }
    
      void addDash(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashLength) {
        // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
        final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashLength);
        final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashLength);
        // Add path
        final pathSegment = metric.extractPath(extractedPathLength, end);
        path.addPath(pathSegment, Offset.zero);
        // Update
        final delta = _remainingDashLength - (end - extractedPathLength);
        _remainingDashLength = _updateRemainingLength(
          delta: delta,
          end: end,
          availableEnd: availableEnd,
          initialLength: dashLength,
        );
        extractedPathLength = end;
        _previousWasDash = true;
      }
    
      void addDashGap(ui.PathMetric metric, double dashGapLength) {
        // Calculate lengths (actual + available)
        final end = _calculateLength(metric, _remainingDashGapLength);
        final availableEnd = _calculateLength(metric, dashGapLength);
        // Move path's end point
        ui.Tangent tangent = metric.getTangentForOffset(end)!;
        path.moveTo(tangent.position.dx, tangent.position.dy);
        // Update
        final delta = end - extractedPathLength;
        _remainingDashGapLength = _updateRemainingLength(
          delta: delta,
          end: end,
          availableEnd: availableEnd,
          initialLength: dashGapLength,
        );
        extractedPathLength = end;
        _previousWasDash = false;
      }
    
      double _calculateLength(ui.PathMetric metric, double addedLength) {
        return math.min(extractedPathLength + addedLength, metric.length);
      }
    
      double _updateRemainingLength({
        required double delta,
        required double end,
        required double availableEnd,
        required double initialLength,
      }) {
        return (delta > 0 && availableEnd == end) ? delta : initialLength;
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: How to specify line color from point to point.

The answer for me is very acceptable, especially since I have to delve into CustomPainter

thank you so much @Tung

Comment: To specify the line color from point to point, you need to separate the path into multiple segments and then draw each one on the canvas. I can modify the example code to allow setting the color for each line if you prefer.

Comment: I hope so, anytime you want, and I will be very grateful to you for your efforts. Also, I have a new question and I cannot test the code currently. If you modify the position of Widget in the middle It may be at the beginning or the end, or it may even be in the middle of the list What things must be modified to make the line become vertical as opposed to Semicircular?

Comment: @MohaMed I have updated the answer for the set path color. About the "Widget" you mentioned, you're talking about the Question Mark Widget in my example? 
If yes then you will have to play with the `_customPath` and the `Stack` to make it done.
`_customPath` is where the path is defined. 
`Stack` is where the "Question Mark Widget" is drawn on UI to match with the path.

Comment: My example above represents a fixed design for this type of roadmap. It is not as simple as fixing just 1 or 2 parameters, and it can be adapted for other designs as well. There are numerous possibilities with `CustomPainter`. I encourage you to refer to my example and achieve your desired outcome. Good luck!

Comment: You helped me realize the idea and result
Thank you very much for your effort and time.
@TungHa

Answer (score -1):

check
this sample
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'RoadMap UI',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: RoadMapScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class RoadMapScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('RoadMap UI'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RoadMapMilestone(text: 'Start'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapLine(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapMilestone(text: 'Milestone 1'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapLine(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapMilestone(text: 'Milestone 2'),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapLine(),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            RoadMapMilestone(text: 'End'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoadMapMilestone extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const RoadMapMilestone({required this.text});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 120,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.blue,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RoadMapLine extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 2,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Container(
              width: 8,
              height: 2,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned.fill(
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: DottedLinePainter(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class DottedLinePainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.grey
      ..strokeWidth = 2;

    double dashWidth = 5;
    double dashSpace = 5;
    double startY = 1;

    while (startY < size.width) {
      canvas.drawLine(
          Offset(startY, 0), Offset(startY + dashWidth, 0), paint);
      startY += dashWidth + dashSpace;
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).